# To import zip file into postgres

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a csv file which is zipped and it should be imported to a table in postgres .

MY csv file : emp_test.csv

```
EMP_ID  EMP_NAME EMP_SALARY
1         Mike     100
2         Dave     200
3         Justin   300
```

My table emp : `CREATE TABLE EMP (EMP_ID INT , EMP_NAME TEXT ,EMP_SALARY INT ) ;`

MY code :

```
\copy emp from 'C:\Documents' 'unzip -p emp_test.zip' DELIMITER ',';
```

I get permission denied error . If i simply try with

If i just copy normal csv file it works

`\copy emp from 'C:\Documents\emp_test.csv' DELIMITER',' CSV HEADER;` -- this works but if i zipped the file and then try it throws permission denied error Could anyone advise

Comment: either specify `FROM 'filename'` or `FROM PROGRAM 'program'` not both

Comment: Hi David , Thanks for your reply . Can you elaborate pointing my mistakes in the code . Sorry for asking it . I’m New to Postgres .

Comment: The syntax of the command is documented [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS-COPY).  You are trying to run a command so you must specify `from program 'unzip -p em_test.zip'`.

Comment: I tried it throws an error . child process exited with code 9

Comment: well that's down to the command you are trying to execute.  what happens if u run it from the shell?

Comment: thanks for your reply . I am not using shell . I am running from psql tool in pgadmin. I have to configure it to write from shell. is there any blunder I am doing . please kind your advice

Comment: You cannot load a compressed file directly. Uncompress it first, then load it.

Comment: Hi Laurenz ,  Thanks . Could you tell me how should be done as i am new to Postgres . I tried with unzip -c emp_test.zip and then try to load it but it didnt happened

Comment: Hi All, I tried from psql shell with code \copy amp from program 'unzip - p test.zip' delimiter ',' ; still it throws child process exited with code 9 .please advise